# Looking to return the Max value of a Row given a company name

Tags: excel

I have information that is laid out in a table like so:
[image: Table]

What I am trying to achieve is creating a mini dashboard type thing on a separate sheet that would change depending on which company is selected from a drop down, like so:

[image: Dashboard]

In the cell directly under the SRP and Promo Price(s) is where I run into code problems. The goal is to return the max value from SRP row of the table given the Company in the drop down. For example, in my dashboard, I want to be able to drop to say, Company 3, and have the cell showing SRP to equal $5.47.

So far, I have tried maxifs() index/match, with my best luck coming in index(table array, match(company1, customer column,0)), but have been unsuccessful in extracting the max value afterwards. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAXIFS requires all the ranges to be the same size, but we can use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=MAX(INDEX(C:L,MATCH("Company 3",A:A,0),0))
```

[image: This assumes that your lookup table is in A1 Position Start.]